I can't get the same PWM signal on 4 channels over 4 MHz
I control signals of PWM by DMA-burst future in FIFO mode. I use a DMA-burst future to change the dutycycles for four channels of one timer each time when an Update event occurs. FIFO threshold and burst configuration as follows: incremental burst - 8 beats, threshold level - FULL, MSIZE - Half-word.
I don't have any problems as long as I don't increase the frequency above 4 MHz.
signal at 4MHz
However, if I increase the frequency by more than 4 MHz, the pulses become strange and the 4th signal is delayed.
signal at 6MHz
RCC config (216MHz):
    rcc.apb1enr.modify(|_, w| w.pwren().set_bit());
    pwr.cr1.modify(|_, w| w.vos().scale1());
    pwr.cr1.modify(|_, w| w.oden().set_bit());
    while pwr.csr1.read().odrdy().bit_is_clear() {}
    pwr.cr1.modify(|_, w| w.odswen().set_bit());
    while pwr.csr1.read().odswrdy().bit_is_clear() {}

    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.hseon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().hserdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("Hse ready");

    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllsrc().hse());
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.pllm().bits(4)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.plln().bits(216)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllp().div2());

    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.pllon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().pllrdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("Pll ready");

    dp.FLASH.acr.modify(|_, w| w.latency().ws7());
    while !dp.FLASH.acr.read().latency().is_ws7() {}

    rcc.dckcfgr1.modify(|_, w| w.timpre().mul4());

    rcc.cfgr.modify(|_, w| w
        .ppre1().div4()
        .ppre2().div2()
    );

    rcc.cfgr.modify(|_, w| w.sw().pll());
    while !rcc.cfgr.read().sws().is_pll() {}
    println!("pll selectected");

TIM3 config:
    unsafe {
        tim.arr.write(|w| w.bits(35)); // 6MHz
        tim.ccr1().write(|w| w.bits(0));// duty cycle
        tim.ccr2().write(|w| w.bits(0));
        tim.ccr3().write(|w| w.bits(0));
        tim.ccr4().write(|w| w.bits(0));
    }

    tim.ccmr1_output().modify(|_, w| w
        .oc1ce().clear_bit() // clear enable to zero just to be sure
        .oc2ce().clear_bit()
        .oc1pe().enabled() //enable preload
        .oc2pe().enabled()
        .oc1m().pwm_mode1() // set pwm mode 1
        .oc2m().pwm_mode1()
    );

    tim.ccmr2_output().modify(|_, w| w
        .oc3ce().clear_bit() // clear enable to zero just to be sure
        .oc4ce().clear_bit()
        .oc3pe().enabled() //enable preload
        .oc4pe().enabled()
        .oc3m().pwm_mode1() // set pwm mode 1
        .oc4m().pwm_mode1()
    );
    
    // enable output
    tim.ccer.write(|w| w
        .cc1e().set_bit()
        .cc2e().set_bit()
        .cc3e().set_bit()
        .cc4e().set_bit()
    );
    // enable auto-reload
    tim.cr1.modify(|_, w| w.arpe().set_bit());

    tim.dier.modify(|_, w| w.ude().set_bit());
    tim.dier.modify(|_, w| w.cc1de().clear_bit());
    tim.dier.modify(|_, w| w.cc2de().clear_bit());
    tim.dier.modify(|_, w| w.cc3de().clear_bit());
    tim.dier.modify(|_, w| w.cc4de().clear_bit());
    
    tim.dcr.modify(|_, w| w.dba().bits(13));
    tim.dcr.modify(unsafe {
        |_, w| w.dbl().bits(0b11)
    });
    // enable update generation - needed at first start
    tim.egr.write(|w| w.ug().set_bit());
    tim.egr.write(|w| w.ug().set_bit());
    // start pwm
    tim.cr1.modify(|_, w| w.cen().set_bit());

DMA config:
        let dmar_addr = tim.dmar.as_ptr() as u32;

        const ONE_THIRD: u16 = 12;
        const TWO_THIRD: u16 = 24;

        static mut DMA_BUF: [u16; 16] = [
            ONE_THIRD, ONE_THIRD, ONE_THIRD, ONE_THIRD,
            TWO_THIRD, TWO_THIRD, TWO_THIRD, TWO_THIRD,
            ONE_THIRD, ONE_THIRD, ONE_THIRD, ONE_THIRD,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
        ];

        dma1.st[2].fcr.modify(|_, w| w
            .dmdis().set_bit()
            .fth().full()
        );

        dma1.st[2].m0ar.write(|w| w.m0a().bits(DMA_BUF.as_ptr() as u32));
        dma1.st[2].ndtr.write(|w| w.ndt().bits(DMA_BUF.len() as u16));
        dma1.st[2].par.write(|w| w.pa().bits(dmar_addr));

        dma1.st[2].cr.reset();
        dma1.st[2].cr.modify(|_, w| w
            .chsel().bits(5)
            .mburst().incr8()
            .pburst().incr8()
            .pl().very_high()
            .msize().bits16()
            .psize().bits16() 
            .minc().set_bit()
            .pinc().clear_bit()
            .circ().enabled()
            .dir().memory_to_peripheral()
            .teie().clear_bit()
            .htie().clear_bit()
            .tcie().clear_bit()
            .en().enabled()
        );

